# JS - Calling an Object by one of it's properties

Tags: javascript, object, higher-order-functions

I'm making a new object so that I can associate one of the properties to the object itself:

```
 var byVert = {};
 verticesClosest3.forEach(function (x){
     byVert[x.vertix] = x;
  });
```

The first object in `byVert` corresponds to the first object of `verticesClosest3` as one would expect.
 But from the second object on only the `vertex` property corresponds while other properties don't.

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/ao499t4t/1/)**

*The problem probably lies in how I'm building the original-object, in the fiddle you can see that.*

Comment: Please clarify the question. It is not clear what is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I understood the problem: there are a lot of vertices in verticesClosest3 that have the same vertix value; so simply the byVert shows all the same data that are in verticesClosest3 but in different order. Look at the image to see a couple of them. [image: same index vertices]